# How to solve SQL injection issue when the part of query is formed by replacing substring?

Tags: java, sql, sql-injection

In my Java class, I have my method like this. I am getting sql injection in sql.replaceAll line when I run static code analysis. `studentFilter` value looks like, `schoolName = 'ABCD' AND state = 'TEXAS'`. How to resolve this issue? As per me, we can't use PreparedStatement here.

```
private Long getStudentCount(String studentFilter) {
private final NamedParameterJdbcTemplate template; //This is declared at class level
private static final String sql = "select count(name) from student 
                                   wheree marks > 90 AND
                                   dateOfBirth = :dob AND
                                   ( --STUDENT_CONFIG--)";
MapSqlParameterSource sqlParams= new MapSqlParameterSource ();
sqlParams.addValue("dob", "19900101");

return template.queryForObject(sql.replaceAll("--STUDENT_CONFIG--", studentFilter, sqlParams, Long.class)

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include what `studentFilter` contains and what you expect the resulting query to be.

Answer (score 1):

You should NOT use `String` type for  `studentFilter` and this would solve your problem:

```
interface Condition {
    String propertyName();  // Could be checked against explicit list of allowed names
    String operation();     // Could be checked against explicit list of operations
    String expectedValue(); // Could be injected through placeholder
}

List<Condition> studentFilter = ...

for (int i = 0; i < studentFilter.size(); i++) {
    Condition c = studentFilter.get(i);
    sql += " AND " + c.propertyName() + " " + c.operation() + " :placeHolder" + i;
    sqlParams.addValue("placeHolder" + i, c.expectedValue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I haven't worked with NamedParameterJdbcTemplate, but the logic should be fine.

Instead of replacing **student config** with replace methods, try to make parametrized query using **PreparedStatement** / **PreparedStatementCreator** (in your case), that can prevent SQL injections

More about the subject: https://www.baeldung.com/sql-injection

More about PreparedStatment in NamedParameterJdbcTemplate: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html

Comment: He's not allowed use PreparedStatement.

Answer (score 0):

Just parameterise your Student Config the same way you've done for DOB, IE

```
   sqlParams.addValue("studentConfig", studentFilter);

   return template.queryForObject(sql, sqlParams, Long.class);
```

Comment: Does that work when `studentFilter` is not a value but a whole clause like `schoolName = 'ABCD' AND state = 'TEXAS'`?

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca very valid point I never considered really.